# End kernel panic not syncing cannot allocate swiotlb buffer and cannot provide with dma bouncer buffer

Tags: kernel

[image]I am using raspberry pi 4b after successfully installation of raspbian os i connected the pi with raspberry display (official raspberry pi 7 inch display) then error msg appears as kernel panic cant allocate swiotlb buffer before and cant allocate dmabouncer buffer now
Please help

Comment: `successfully installation of os` which OS? where did you get it from? I wonder if you can take a picture of the whole screen rather than part of it - also what is this `raspberry display` you've connected to?

Comment: I have installed raspbian os and display is official raspberry pi 7 inch display. Photo is of whole screen only one line is not visible.

Comment: **Raspbian** is outdated. You should use the up to date [Raspberry Pi OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/).

Comment: was hoping to see the last SUCCESSFUL boot operation just above what you've taken a picture of -  maybe connect to a TV/Monitor - you may see more above the error to be able to pinpoint where in the boot process it has failed

Comment: confirming one more thing - other than the 7 inch raspberry pi display, you have nothing else connected to the pi and have made absolutely no changes to the boot partition?

Comment: I am having the same issue here after installing a fresh "Raspberry Pi OS" 2020, and changing some of the settings in raspi-config

Answer (score 8):

I ran into this same issue with a new install of Pi OS after setting the GPU memory to 896 MB in raspi-config.

To fix it without reinstalling:

1. Put the SD card in another computer that can read the "boot" filesystem. I believe it is a FAT32 filesystem.
2. Open "config.txt" and alter the "gpu_mem" setting. Set it to something like 512 or lower.

I don't know what the upper limit is, but 512 worked for me and is recommended as the maximum value for a Pi with 1GB memory or greater.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/memory.md

Comment: The upper limit is 512. Nobody should need that amount of GPU RAM, Start with 192 and work from there.

Comment: Just hit this... why is the upper limit in the UI widget 896?

Comment: Had the same issues. After reading a bit, this setting is really just for video decoding and the desktop -- 3d applications override this anyway, so no need to set it so high.

Comment: You are amazing, thank you. I am another dumb-dumb who maxed my GPU to 896 even when the internet told me 512 was the max lol.